# Comparison of two values from a column in pandas dataframe causing a TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, comparison

I'm trying to build a new column in my pandas dataframe, `raw_data`, called `CyclesTest`. I want it to contain a value, `cycle_test`, that begins at 1. Every row of this column will contain the number 1, until a condition is met in a comparison of the values in another column of the dataframe, `Step`, where the value of the next 'step' is less than the one that the if loop has reached. At that point, `CyclesTest` would increase by 1, and continue to the end of the dataframe.

This is my code so far:

```
raw_data['CyclesTest'] = " "
cycle_test = 1

for i in (raw_data.index):
    if  raw_data['Step'][i] > raw_data['Step'][i+1]:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
        cycle_test+=1
    else:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
        
    
print(incefa_raw_curve_data['CyclesTest'])
```

However, I get this error on the comparison line:

```
if  raw_data['Step'][i] > raw_data['Step'][i+1]:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

This is an output of the column, `Step`

```
print(raw_data['Step'])

0        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
        ..
51790    7
51791    7
51792    7
51793    7
51794    7
```

Why would I get the comparison error if `step` only contains integer values? I tried to cast both values to `int` which just caused more errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

pls explain the code. show all your code so i can understand what are you trying to do

```py
raw_data = {"Step":[1,2,3,4,5]}
raw_data['CyclesTest'] = {}
cycle_test = 1
try:
    for i in range(1,11):
        if  raw_data['Step'][i] > raw_data['Step'][i+1]:
            raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
            cycle_test+=1
        else:
            raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    print(raw_data['CyclesTest'])
```

is that what are you trying to do?
i have no idea

```py
raw_data = {"Step":[1,2,3,4,5],"stuff":True,"_":"","dict":{},"list":[],"int":int(0/1),"float":0/1,"str":"abc"}
raw_data['CyclesTest'] = {}
cycle_test = 1
print(raw_data)
for i in range(len(raw_data)-len(raw_data["Step"])):
    print(i)
    if  raw_data['Step'][i] > raw_data['Step'][i+1]:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test
        cycle_test+=1
    else:
        raw_data['CyclesTest'][i] = cycle_test


print(raw_data['CyclesTest'])
```

Please add more details

Comment: Thanks, but I have added as much as I can with regards to this function. I want `cycle_test` to start at one, and if the value in `raw_data['Step'][i+1]` is less than the value at `raw_data[i]`, I want to increment `cycle_test` by 1 and append the value to the new column, `raw_data['CyclesTest']`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).